# How to subset and generate a large data frame with Python Dash?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a Dash app that must:

1. Read a csv file and convert it to a dataframe
2. Subset this dataframe according to the user's choices (radio buttons,...)
3. Generate the subseted dataframe in a csv file

The issue is I can't subset the dataframe as I would like.

Let's imagine I got a data frame `gas3` with a variable `Flag`. Here is a part of my code:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc # Graphs
import dash_html_components as html # Tags
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, Event, State
from pandas_datareader import DataReader
import time
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
import random
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
import statistics
from datetime import *
from pytz import *
import dash_table_experiments as dte
import io
from flask import send_file
import flask
import urllib.parse

# Import df

gas3 = pd.read_csv("D:/Path/gas3.csv", sep=';')
gas3['Date_Local_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(gas3['Date_Local_Time'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M') # Conversion de la variable en type "date heure"

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets) # Starting application

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

# Radio buttons

    html.Div([
            html.Label("Sélectionnez la valeur du Flag que vous souhaitez :",
                    htmlFor='radioflag',
                    ),
            html.Br(),
            html.Br(),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                    id='radioflag',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'Flag 0', 'value': 'Flag0'},
                        {'label': 'Flag 1', 'value': 'Flag1'},
                        {'label': 'Flag 3', 'value': 'Flag3'},
                        {'label': 'Chambre à flux', 'value': 'CAF'}
                        ]
                        ),
            html.Br(),
            ]),

# Download button

    html.Div(id='table'),
    html.A(
        'Download Data',
        id='download-link',
        download="rawdata.csv",
        href="",
        target="_blank"
    )
])

### Subset function

def filter_data(flag):
    gas_genere = gas3.copy()
    if flag == 'Flag0':
        gas_genere = gas_genere[gas_genere['Flag']==0]
        return gas_genere
    else:
        return gas_genere[0:4]

# Callback

@app.callback(
    Output('download-link', 'href'),
    [Input('radioflag', 'value')])
def update_download_link(flag):
    gas_genere = filter_data(flag)
    csv_string = gas_genere.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep=';')
    csv_string = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + urllib.parse.quote(csv_string)
    return csv_string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I found out the issue but I don't know how to fix it. If I change my `filter_data` function to (I just added `[0:2]` to the first `return gas_genere`) :

```py
def filter_data(flag):
    gas_genere = gas3.copy()
    if flag == 'Flag0':
        gas_genere = gas_genere[gas_genere['Flag']==0]
        return gas_genere[0:2]
    else:
        return gas_genere[0:4]
```

The app works well! If I check "Flag 0", `gas_genere[0:2]` will be generated. Else, `gas_genere[0:4]` will be generated.

But if I keep it like in my original code, I can check "Flag 1", "Flag 3", "Chambre à flux" or don't check any button, it would work and generate `gas_genere[0:4]`. But if I check "Flag 0", instead of returning `gas_genere`, I would not get a csv file, but would get an error: "téléchargement Echec - Erreur réseau." which in English should be "Download Failed - Network Error".

I tryed to generate my dataframe `gas_genere = gas3[gas3['Flag']==0]` in Python and it got 14299 rows and 43 columns.

Is my dataframe too large? If so, what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: How big is the csv file (in mb)? Do you see any error in your application log/std out?

Comment: My csv file is very large (almost 2M rows for 44 columns). gas3 is 806 mb and gas4 96. The only solution I found is to go on Firefox (I was using Chrome) and it works well even if the file generation is slow. Don't see any error in my application log!

Comment: Have you tried to look at the network tab in the chrome dev tools to see if the query is failing in chrome (https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/chrome-network-tab)

Comment: Nope, I haven't seen any error :/